# uploadifive - change filename on upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadifive to upload images - however I want to change the name of the images to "newimage" I am not sure where or how to do this with what is provided - this is the last modification I need to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to do the name change in the PHP script that handles the uploading (I'm assuming your using PHP since that's uplidfy's standard). It can be a bit tricky because you have to separate the incoming file name from it's extension. This should be enough to get you started.

```
    $theFile = $_FILES['file_upl']['name'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file_upl']['tmp_name'];
    $newName = "newname";
    $saveDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/";

    //Function returns the extension from the '.' on
    function get_ext($from_file) { 
        $ext = strtolower(strrchr($from_file,'.'));
        return $ext;
    }

    //This will rename the file to $newname + the extension
    $theFile = $newname.get_ext($theFile);

//Save the file
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$saveDir.$theFile);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$file = 'uploaded_img.jpg';
$remote_file = 'Saved.txt';

ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)
```

just change the name of the remote file